# TikZ — archimedean spiral precision problem?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \clip[] (-26, -26) rectangle (26, 26);

    \foreach \a in {0, 30,..., 330} {
        \foreach \r in {4,8,...,24} {
            \draw[line width=0.05mm] ({\r*cos(-5+\a)}, {\r*sin(-5+\a)}) arc ({-5+\a}:{5+\a}:{\r});
        }
    }

    \foreach \a in {0, 30,..., 330} {
        \foreach \r in {0,4,...,24} {
            \draw[line width=0.05mm] ({(\r-1)*cos(\a)}, {(\r-1)*sin(\a)}) -- ({(\r+1)*cos(\a)}, {(\r+1)*sin(\a)});
        }
    }       

    % Spiral
    \draw[blue, line cap=round, line width=0.25mm, domain=0:pi, variable=\t, samples=5000]
        plot ({-\t r}:{(8*\t)});    

    % Dots
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
        \fill[red] ({(\x*4)*cos(-\x*30)}, {(\x*4)*sin(-\x*30)}) circle (0.4mm); 
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The blue archimedean spiral should visit every red point but it doesn't. I double checked the calculations but can't find the error.

[image: archimedean spiral]
[image: error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just replace  `plot ({-\t r}:{(8*\t)})` with `plot ({-\t r}:{(24/pi*\t)})`

**Your code**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \clip[] (-26, -26) rectangle (26, 26);

    \foreach \a in {0, 30,..., 330} {
        \foreach \r in {4,8,...,24} {
            \draw[line width=0.05mm] ({\r*cos(-5+\a)}, {\r*sin(-5+\a)}) arc ({-5+\a}:{5+\a}:{\r});
        }
    }

    \foreach \a in {0, 30,..., 330} {
        \foreach \r in {0,4,...,24} {
            \draw[line width=0.05mm] ({(\r-1)*cos(\a)}, {(\r-1)*sin(\a)}) -- ({(\r+1)*cos(\a)}, {(\r+1)*sin(\a)});
        }
    }       

    % Spiral
    \draw[blue, line cap=round, line width=0.25mm, domain=0:pi, variable=\t, samples=5000]
        plot ({-\t r}:{(24/pi*\t)});    

    % Dots
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
        \fill[red] ({(\x*4)*cos(-\x*30)}, {(\x*4)*sin(-\x*30)}) circle (0.4mm); 
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]